# Regex to validate macros in text

Tags: regex, parsing, macros, escaping, text-parsing

I'm trying to build a Regex to validate the text which can contain macros in the format:

```
Some text (*MacroIDInsert*) some text continues..
```

I would like to detect cases when the macro was not

1. Closed correctly (e.g. "(*" without closing "*)" )
2. Opened correctly (e.g. "*)" without opening "(*" )

Example invalid cases I would like to detect:

```
Some text (* Invalid Macro Insert some text (*ValidMacroInsert*)
```

or

```
Some text Invalid Macro Insert *) some text (*ValidMacroInsert*)
```

I would like to match the (* or *) that are missing the accompanying bracket. And possibly replace the "bad" ones with < and > accordingly, for example:

```
Some text Invalid Macro Insert > some text (*ValidMacroInsert*)
```

Would that be achievable using regex?

UPDATE:
Further clarification revealed that text may contain *nested* macros, e.g.:

```
Some text (*MacroID1(*MacroID2*)*) some text continues..
```

In this case, my understanding is that it would be impossible to judge which of the "invalid" brackets to replace...
For example, consider the following structure:

```
(*id1*) (*id2*) (* (*id3*) (* id5 (*id4*) *)
                ^^?        ^^?
```

In this case we don't know which of the two marked (above) brackets are incorrect...

Comment: Which language are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your language supports `PCRE` verb, `(*SKIP)(*F)`, i did use.

```
\(\*(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*\*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\(\*|\*\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/1)

That is, use this `\(\*(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*\*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\(\*` regex and then replace the matched characters with [`<`](https://regex101.com/r/dL7jZ6/3) then use this regex `\(\*(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*\*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\*\)` against the modified string and replace the matched characters with `>`

I love the variable length lookbehind feature in `C#`

```
string str = @"Some text (* Invalid Macro Insert some text (*ValidMacroInsert*)
Some text Invalid Macro Insert *) some text (*ValidMacroInsert*)";
string result1 = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?m)\(\*(?=(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*\(|$)", "<");
string result2 = Regex.Replace(result1, @"(?<!\(\*(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*)\*\)", ">");
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pjuxe7)

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash, although I use the .NET regex engine, I think it does not support the PCRE verbs (unless PCRE C# wrapper is used, but unfortunately I cannot use it at the moment...)

Comment: to match the closing `)*`, try this `(?<!\(\*(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*)\*\)`

Comment: oh, you could reduce the first regex to `\(\*(?!(?:(?!\(\*|\*\)).)*\*\))`

Comment: Awesome, but now I start to understand why this was not yet implemented in our system - there's one specific requirement that I think makes it almost impossible to escape invalid tags properly... I will update the original question with these specifics.

Comment: I will accept your answer, as it solved the originally asked question :) But the nested macros question is a bit complicated... :(

Comment: @SomeOne not a bit, it's lot more complicated . Ask the nested macros as new question.